# schedule on task at a time - java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have a task that is scheduled periodically. Sometime it can take longer than expected.
I am trying to find a way to make sure that scheduling will be canceled in case the task is already running. All mechanisms I check will make the task wait and run it after the first finish

locking ofcourse will do the job but I'm looking of something more high level

Any Idea

Comment: Create a flag variable. Set it to true before and to false after task execution. Check its value and skip the task.

Comment: @talex Well, the OP was asking for "something more high level". I wouldn't say flags fit into that category.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ScheduledExecutorService`. [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) is probably what you want as it will wait for your tasks to finish, iff one takes longer than the *rate* you specify:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

Example:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    // Body will be executed every second unless the previous task hasn't finished.
}, 0L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This means that when the late task will finish the next iteration will immediately start. Is there a way that is will start on the next scheduling point?

Comment: @user1109846 How about [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)? Tasks are executed "with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next".

Comment: @user1109846 Please accept the best answer if your problem has been solved. If not, please try to edit the question to improve it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called scheduleAtFixedRate and scheduleAtFixedDelay.

scheduleAtFixedRate will start another process at defined time, so if previous process is not completed, two processes will be running and it might cause race condition of running same thing twice.

scheduleAtFixedDelay will start after fixed time once a task is completed.

[scheduleAtFixedRate vs scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649842/scheduleatfixedrate-vs-schedulewithfixeddelay)

In Spring you can do this by using annotation:-

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay =30000)
```

http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/

Answer (score 0):

do you know Apache Camel framework?
It has a module called quartz2 and has a much possibility to scheduling any task.

try read this page: 
http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html