# Avoid busy-waiting warning in a thread

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
public void foo(AtomicBoolean close){

    new Thread(() -> {

        try{

            System.out.println("foo started");

            while(!close.get()){

                System.out.print("working");
                //peace of code for execution.

                //wait 1 second before re-execute the same thing.
                //warning: Call to 'Thread.sleep()' in a loop, probably busy-waiting
                try{ Thread.sleep(1_000); /*1sec*/ }catch(Exception ignored){}

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("foo stopped");
        

    }, "fooThread").start();

}
```

The code works, but I want to get rid of that warning and I don't see how I can rewrite this piece of code.

The `close` is just for knowing when the thread should stop.

Comment: This code looks like just some piece of testing code so I'd suggest you just ignore the warning. In real code you might want to think about using a `CompletableFuture` etc. instead of busy waiting for the result of `close.get()`. There might be other approaches as well, it all depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve and the rest of your design.

Comment: Awaitility might be useful.

Comment: @NathanHughes I think Awaitility is just busy-waiting, but wrapped in a library. It would remove the warning but not actually fix anything. If that's the goal, you may as well just suppress the warning rather than introduce a dependency.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm not really waiting for close to change. The close is for knowing when the thread should stop.

Comment: Well, if your thread doesn't do anything else that simulate some work (which I assume the `Thread.sleep(1000)` is meant to do) then there's not much you can do. You _could_ use waits and notifications but that would change the properties of your approach. Since this is just test code don't bother with the warning on `Thread.sleep()` for now.

Comment: @KunLun: can you restructure your code into tasks? It seems like one of the jobs of your thread is "waiting some time until we do the thing again" and that seems wasteful. You could have a small thread pool (maybe even a single thread) and schedule tasks in it in some set interval instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, yes, this is the point of the code. To re-execute something after a specific wait. "schedule tasks in it in some set interval" I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Check the [`ScheduledExecutorService` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: What I'd the warning coming from? It seems like a static analysis thing,  it likely doesn't even take into account that the thread is sleeping. This really isn't busy waiting, there is not an issue beyond making the warning go away.

Comment: @NathanHughes It's an intellij warning, I've seen the same wording before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd write it. You don't necessarily need the class, it just encapsulates the executor and task nicely.

In addition to `scheduleWithFixedDelay`, there's also `scheduleAtFixedRate`. The difference is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649842/scheduleatfixedrate-vs-schedulewithfixeddelay). I chose the one that's closest to your code.

```
class FooService
{ 
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private volatile ScheduledFuture<?> task;
    
    public void start() {
        if (task != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Already started");
        }

        task = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
            System.out.println("working");
            // piece of code for execution.
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        task.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need different tools to make this work. You can't ask an `AtomicBoolean` to wait until its value changes, but that's what you want to do, so you're using the wrong tool for the job.

A better tool would e.g. be a `j.u.c.Lock` variant, latch, or similar. Or, if you want to do it with java's built-in primitives, `wait()` and `notify()`:

```
synchronized (close) {
  while (!close.get()) {
    close.wait();
  }
}
```

and where-ever you change that AtomicBoolean:

```
synchronized (close) {
  close.set(false);
  close.notifyAll();
}
```

Threading is tricky, in that any errors you make are not (easily) discovered even if you write fairly extensive unit tests; actual behaviour depends on OS, hardware, VM version, and phase of the moon.

Comment: I'm not really waiting for close. The close is for knowing when the thread should stop.

Comment: So what _ARE_ you waiting for then? If this is just example code, where `Thread.sleep` is taking the place of 'eventually I'll do some actual work here', then this problem will go away once you replace it.